# How to move app to second monitor when hidden behind full screen remote desktop on first screen?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop

- When working from home I use an RDP session on the first monitor right in front of me.
- When not working (no RDP session open) I tend to drag apps to the first monitor as well (because: right in front).
  Let's say I did this with my mail program (Thunderbird).

Now comes the next working day, I open RDP, fullscreen by default. I want to look at my local mail and start Thunderbird. It opens *behind* the full screen RDP session on the first monitor. The only thing I can access for Thunderbird (without minimizing the RDP session) is the task bar icon.

How can I now quickly move Thunderbird to my second monitor?

- Right-clicking does not focus the app, so the usual <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Arrow</kbd> does not work.
- I would expect clicking the second desktop, then Alt-Tabbing to the app, then do <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Arrow</kbd> to work, but it does neither.

Windows 10. I have Snap Assist turned *off*.

Comment: Reduce your RDP window by placing your mouse pointer close to the top of your screen; the RDP control bar will slide down, and you can reduce the window without closing it. Then you can move your other app window to your other screen, and bring RDP back to fullscreen.

Comment: @Didier The whole point is that I do not want to have to close/miminize RDP. I used the word 'quickly', like e.g. one click and a key combination. Or maybe a few key combinations without having to bother about location the mouse.

Comment: I understand, but Alt-Tab is inhibited when running RDP in fullscreen mode, which means you *have* to minimize the window to be able to Alt-Tab your way around all active applications on your Desktop. That or resize your RDP windows to occupy most, not all of your main screen. You'd have to do it ONCE...